# Right click event on google map api with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

Well I can capture a click on my google map to do some tasks but what i need now is a right click on the map. I found that I should use a Directive. using that means that i can add ng-right-click on my HTML but what i'm doing is like so :

Here is my code

```
 $scope.map  ={
    ......
        events: {
            tilesloaded: function (map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                //map is trueley ready then this callback is hit
            },
            click: function (mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                var lat = e.latLng.lat(), lon = e.latLng.lng();
            }
        }
    }
```

what i want is the the same thing that **Click** does but with right mouse click how can I capture this event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a list of all events in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) (with a working demo). It seems like you are looking for the **rightclick** event

Comment: That was Silly from me!! I thought that i should add a Directive but **rightclick** exist already i should just add :

rightclick: function (mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                var lat = e.latLng.lat(), lon = e.latLng.lng();
            }

Thank you :)